# firebase functions deployment complete in terminal, but firebase console doesn't reflect these changes

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to google firebase cloud functions. I successfully deployed the backend of my project when I used the terminal. Here is a screenshot for reference:
[image]

However, when I check my google firebase console, it doesn't reflect this. It only shows the last time I tried to deploy this app, which resulted in a fail. Here are some screenshots for reference:
[image]

Here's another screenshot:
[image]

It doesn't show the most recent, successful deployment. I'm not sure why it's not updating.

I started this project last year, but stopped working on it for a while. Only recently did I start working on it again. Could it be that firebase.json is outdated? Do I have to restart the whole firebase process again. Although I'm not sure how to do that. Any ideas on how to fix this problem? Any help is appreciated! Thanks!